# How to transpose/pivot and group columns to rows in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pivot-table

I have data that looks like this:

```
Date Sales1 Sales2 Sales3

date1 1.1  1.2  1.3
date2 2.1  2.2  2.3
date3 3.1  3.2  3.3
```

The desired output is to add a second column for better visibility and pivot the columns

```
Date SalesType Sales

date1 Sales1 1.1
date1 Sales2 1.2
date1 Sales3 1.3
date2 Sales1 2.1
date2 Sales2 2.2
date2 Sales3 2.3
date3 Sales1 3.1
date3 Sales2 3.2
date3 Sales3 3.3
```

Is there a way to get that type of pivot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
res = (df.melt(id_vars='Date', var_name='Sales_Type',value_name='Sales')
       .sort_values('Date')
       .reset_index(drop=True))

print(res)

    Date Sales_Type  Sales
0  date1     Sales1    1.1
1  date1     Sales2    1.2
2  date1     Sales3    1.3
3  date2     Sales1    2.1
4  date2     Sales2    2.2
5  date2     Sales3    2.3
6  date3     Sales1    3.1
7  date3     Sales2    3.2
8  date3     Sales3    3.3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```py
df = df.set_index('Date').stack().reset_index()
df.columns=['Date', 'SalesType', 'Sales']
```

Full test code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['date1','date2','date3'], 'Sales1':[1.1,2.1,3.1], 'Sales2':[1.2,2.2,3.2], 'Sales3':[1.3,2.3,3.3]})
print(df)
df = df.set_index('Date').stack().reset_index()
df.columns=['Date', 'SalesType', 'Sales']
print(df)
```

Input:

```
    Date  Sales1  Sales2  Sales3
0  date1     1.1     1.2     1.3
1  date2     2.1     2.2     2.3
2  date3     3.1     3.2     3.3
```

Output:

```
    Date SalesType  Sales
0  date1    Sales1    1.1
1  date1    Sales2    1.2
2  date1    Sales3    1.3
3  date2    Sales1    2.1
4  date2    Sales2    2.2
5  date2    Sales3    2.3
6  date3    Sales1    3.1
7  date3    Sales2    3.2
8  date3    Sales3    3.3
```

**UPDATE**:

For fun, if your version of python supports the walrus operator (technically, the "conditional operator") `:=`, you can do it in one line like this:

```py
(df := df.set_index('Date').stack().reset_index()).columns=['Date', 'SalesType', 'Sales']
```